# Considering the theory of special relativity: Is torque still a vector?

Tags: special-relativity, vectors, torque, tensor-calculus

Considering the theory of special relativity: Is torque still a vector?

In classical mechanics it is easy: You have 3 axes and thus 3 planes. Every plane has its own torque so torque has 3 dimensions and thus can be represented as a vector.

How are torques represented in the theory of special relativity? You have 4 axes and thus 6 planes and each of them has its own torque.

Comment: Torque has never been a vector, it has always been a *pseudovector*. (And that, more abstractly a 2-form, it remains)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since torque is defined as the rate of change of angular momentum, the more fundamental question would be whether angular momentum is a vector in SR. The answer is no, because there is no vector cross product in four dimensions. Angular momentum is a rank-2 tensor.